# Splitting CSV, but not on comma only (PHP)?

Tags: php, csv

I want to split a CSV string. The string looks like that:

**"val1","val2","val3, some other stuff", "val4"**

As you see, there can be a comma inside the values (see val3), so using explode on the comma wont work.

I also tried:

```
preg_split('/","/', $myLine)
```

This does not work though, how would I do that otherwise?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please use the search function before asking questions, like you are asked to in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice. [How to parse CSV files has been asked and answered dozens of times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+csv+php). Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) if your data is in a file,

or [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) if your data is a string

Comment: Ah yes, str_getcsv is exactly what I need! Big thanks

Answer (score 2):

For CSV files in PHP function: [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

In 3rd param you can set delimetr, by default - "," (comma)

Function reads every lines and returns array with elements for current line

**Example**:

```
$f = fopen('file.csv', 'r+');
while (($data = fgetcsv($f, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    /* $data is array with elements for current line */
}
fclose($f);
```

Comment: exactly right.  "fgetcsv()" supports "delimiters" (so you can use something besides commas) and "enclosures" (which neatly solves this problem).

Answer (score 2):

```
$inputfiledelimiter="~";
if (($handle = fopen($target_path, "r")) !== FALSE) 
{       
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $inputfiledelimiter)) !== FALSE) 
    {

    }   
}
```