# PHP explode for CSV?

Tags: php

I have data in a CSV file.  I need to read the file and put the data into an array.  I have 5 columns in my CSV file, like this:

```
CAPRICCIOSA | Tomato, Cheese, Mushrooms | $8.00 | $12.00 | $15.00

MARGHERITA  | Tomato, Cheese, Oregano   | $7.00 | $11.00 | $13.00
```

1. How can I`explode()` it into array?  If I use a comma to explode it into array, it will become `CAPRICCIOA - Tomato - Cheese` because my text already has a comma.
2. How can I split it into different rows, like MySQL so I can loop through the results?

I have tried the following:

```
 $file="dish.csv" ;
 $file=file_get_contents($file);
 $array=explode(",", $file);
```

Comment: CSV is comma-separated unless there are commas in the value of a field, in which case the whole field value is enclosed in double quotation marks. You should either go through the text and parse or write a regex to extract. Using explode() the way you're saying won't work here because you need to do more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting CSV, but not on comma only (PHP)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683284/splitting-csv-but-not-on-comma-only-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using PHP function : fgetcsv()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: What a great answer, I was not aware if this function. Props!

Comment: I usually use that function when I work with csv file because I can determine the delimiter for the csv :)

Answer (score 2):

You should turn to fgetcsv:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$fn='dish.csv';

$file_array = file($fn);
foreach ($file_array as $line_number =>&$line)
{
    //$line=utf8_encode($line);
    $row=explode('|',$line);

    echo 'Dish: '.$row[0].'<br>';
    $ingredients=explode(',',$row[1]);
    echo 'Ingredients:';
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($ingredients);
    echo '<br><br>';
    echo '</pre>';
}
```