# How to get multiple string data from mysql into an array format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a mysql table with column "name". in this name i have multiple names, for example  id = 1 , and the name = "Ford","Ferrari","Audi","Wolks"

so in id->1 there is multiple names in column "name" and I want all these names in array format. like this below -->

```
$name = $row['name']; // fetching data from mysql

$show = array ($name);
echo "I like " . $show[0]."<br>";

echo "I don't like " . $show[1]."<br>";
```

So that I can echo only specific name  from unique id..

I hope you're getting what I'm trying to solve.. Thank You.. :)

Comment: I think you want to use `explode`. You should normalize your table though, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad As is it is unclear how you'd know what cars you like/dislike.

Comment: Sorry I don't want to use explode, as it will count every word. Suppose If there I have stored this value "Maruti Suzuki", "Ford Fiesta" etc.. so I in this case won't get unique names by using this explode.

Comment: What is "unique" there?

Comment: sorry i was wrong, explode worked for me,, thanks

Comment: Sorry again.. :) your idea was to use explode worked now..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting CSV, but not on comma only (PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683284/splitting-csv-but-not-on-comma-only-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `explode` function of PHP to get an array of names as like below

For single record

```
$name = $row['name']; // fetching data from mysql
$names_array = explode(',',$name); //use comma separater

echo "I like " . $names_array[0]."<br>";    
echo "I don't like " . $names_array[1]."<br>";
```

For multiple records

```
$names_array = array();
foreach( $rows as $row ) //rows are fetched using mysql query
{
  $names_array = explode(',',$row['name']); //use comma separater

  echo "I like " . $names_array[0]."<br>";    
  echo "I don't like " . $names_array[1]."<br>";
}
```

Hope so it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is stored as:

```
"Ford","Ferrari","Audi"
```

Then you can use: [`str-getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

Although you should consider using [Third Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) instead.